# Unable to install AVD device not found error

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have tried AVD with various names and SD Card size, but still following problem persists:

```
New emulator found: emulator-5554
Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched
HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
Uploading IfElse.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
Installing IfElse.apk...
Success!
Failed to install IfElse.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue because of the Memory issue while opening the Emulator. please close all your programs while launching the emulator and try. and create the lower version of the AVD like Android 2.0 first.

Comment: I closed all other apps but I can't use version 2.0 as I only have 4.0.

Any other possible solution?

Comment: You can get the specific android version from Android SDK manager. and if you wanted to use only 4.0 then you need to upgrade your system

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Virtual Device form the command line instead of AVG Manager. You can do this by running the command below, substituting the directory with your path to `android-sdk-windows\tools`

```
C:\Eclipse\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator -avd [Device name here]
```

If you are behind a proxy define the IP address and port like below;

```
C:\Eclipse\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator -avd [Device name here] -http-proxy 172.16.10.4:8080
```

Once the device has opened up, you may install the apk using the command below (once again substituting the `android-sdk-windows` and APK with path)

```
C:\Eclipse\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb install C:\apps\Android\apk\XBMC Remote.apk
```